# Quicken 2014 opens on 2nd monitor not default after changing other monitor positions

Tags: multiple-monitors, quicken

All other apps not affected. Have incident number with Quicken Tech but that may take months. Feel it is a simple edit in Windows Registry but need what to look for so I can search for it.

Using work-around tenporarily: Windows key/Shift and right arrow key twice to direct login screen to default and number one monitor. Have also tried dragging icon but NG.

Answer (score 0):

[Quicken 2014](https://qlc.intuit.com/questions/167378-faq-font-size-problems) has issue with the resolution of the screen and the DPI setting.

When running high resolutions people want (or the operating system wants in the case of Windows 8.1) to have a DPI setting other than 100% to "scale" everything on the screen, and that scaling doesn't work.

Also there is a bug where if you are using two monitors at the same time and the primary display is a different resolution than the secondary one.

You can either display Quicken on the 2nd monitor or make both displays the same resolution for it to work right.